# OpenCV wont' capture from MacBook Pro iSight

Tags: python, macos, opencv, isight

Since a couple of days I can't open my iSight camera from inside an opencv application any more. `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` returns, and `cap.isOpened()` returns `true`. However, `cap.grab()` just returns `false`. Any ideas?

Example Code:

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rval = True

while rval:
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break
```

- Mac OS 10.8.5
- Python 2.7.5 (but also not working from inside a C++ app)
- OpenCV 2.4.6.1

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm asking again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187076/capturing-from-macbook-pro-isight-with-opencv

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I got the camera working for your code (on OSX 10.6):

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

rval, frame = vc.read()

while True:

  if frame is not None:   
     cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
  rval, frame = vc.read()

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work again after a complete reinstall. Also, maybe it took longer to set up the input channel. A frame actually only comes in on the second or third call to read(). Did not have this problem earlier

Comment: How did you install OpenCV on mac?

Answer (score 1):

I had a segmentation fault after I grab an image. It turned out that I used `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` before  `cap.release()`. Below I show working code.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

#do some ops

cap.release()
cv2.imshow("output", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works on El Captain.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what your code does and how it answers the question?

Comment: @alex-attinger has a problem with grabbing image. I showed my code which grab a picture and works on macOS.

Comment: I understand that your code might solve the problem, but it's a lot more useful if you explain what was wrong with the original and how your code actually solves the question. Especially given this question is from 2013